# How router will send ARP resolve packet when it receive ARP request?

Tags: router, networking, protocol-theory, arp, proxy-arp

How router will send ARP resolve packet when it receive ARP request ??

Router by default enabled with proxy arp configuration?? If then proxy arp is not configured then what will happen if it receives ARP request?

Comment: A router is just a host on the network, and it does ARP like any other host. When a router receives an ARP request, it responds with its MAC address. A host on a network does not send an ARP request for a host on a different network.

Comment: Yeah I got it.. But in what basis router responds with MAC address. Please confirm router will reply only when router enabled with proxy arp functionality?

Comment: A router is a host with IP and MAC addresses, so it works like any other host on the network. When a host on the network needs to resolve the router MAC address for the router IP address, it sends an ARP request, and the router responds with its MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

> How router will send ARP resolve packet when it receive ARP request ?

A router's ARP response doesn't differ from that of any other node.

> Router by default enabled with proxy arp configuration?

No, not at all. Proxy ARP is only used when it is necessary to (fake) resolve remote hosts. It's rarely useful and should not be used carelessly.

> If then proxy arp is not configured then what will happen if it receives ARP request?

ARP requests for the router's IP address are replied to.

You might be wondering *how does ARP work between IP subnets?* It doesn't. MAC-based forwarding only works withing an IP subnet. Between subnets, a router/gateway forwards based on the destination IP.